# PHP escapeshellcmd is escaping Czech language characters

Tags: php, escaping

in my code I pass variables $name and $surname from registration form via post method. I call function in which I pass these variables. If I echo them, they are just fine, until I use escapeshellcmd on them. 
Then all the special characters of Czech language such as: 'ě,š,č,ř,ž,ý,á,í,é' are escaped.
Is there some workaround or another function I could use for safe input from the form? I tried escapeshellarg, but that breaks the code.

Comment: what about encoding your inputs into base64 then decoding it from the other side?

Comment: Do you call anything with `shell_exec` or what it is the need of using `escapeshellcmd` or `escapeshellarg` at this point? These function prepare stuff for running under command line. So, why?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I will try that and let know it it worked.

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions: As I understand, if I have a form like this and then I store inputed data in the database, I need to prevent users from inputing some code that could breach security of the web. And this function should do that. Im not that skilled in PHP, so I could understand it wrong. So are you sure I don´t need to escape inputs in this case?